# onPress event only takes last index of array - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, event-handling

Before you mark this question as a duplicate of a closure issue or a event binding issue, know that I have tried all of those and it does not work.

[A working demo of the issue.](https://snack.expo.io/@sl-a-sh/swipe-test) Open the link. Run the project on android and check logs. If you click on any option in the first question, it will log the `lastIndex` (Here it is 4. Since there are a total of 5 questions) when it should log the `firstIndex` which is 0.

So I am using javascript `map` to loop over my questions array and return questions and their respective options. Inside I have another `map` to loop over options.

The checkbox is a `react-native-elements` component.

```
  renderCard = (item, index) => {
    return (
      <Card style={styles.testCard}>
        <View key={item.u_question_id}>
          <Text style={styles.question}>{index + 1}. {item.question}</Text>
          {item.options.map(({ option, checked }, i) => {
            return (
              <View key={i}>
                <CheckBox
                  containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", borderWidth: 0 }}
                  title={option}
                  checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                  uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                  checked={checked}
                  onPress={() => this.onSelectOption(index, i)}
                />
              </View>
            )
          })}
        </View>
      </Card>
    )
  }
```

What I am expecting is that `onPress` of a checkbox should send the `questionIndex` and the `optionIndex` into `onSelectOption` to change the state and view but `onPress` always sends the last index of the questions array so the options of the last question are getting changed and not the intended one.

My `onSelectOption` method. Here `questionIndex` is coming 4 if I have 5 questions even though I am pressing on the first question's options.

```
  onSelectOption = (questionIndex, optionIndex) => {
    const selectedLanguageQuestionsCopy = this.state.selectedLanguageQuestions;
    selectedLanguageQuestionsCopy[questionIndex].options.forEach(option => {
      option.checked = false;
    });
    selectedLanguageQuestionsCopy[questionIndex].options[optionIndex].checked = true;
    
    this.setState({ assessmentData: selectedLanguageQuestionsCopy });
  }
```

I have tried using:

1. `onPress={() => this.onSelectOption(index, i)}`
2. `onPress={this.onSelectOption.bind(this, index, i)}` and changing onSelectOption to a normal method instead of an array function.

But it does not work. I am always getting the last index of the questions array.

The place where I am calling the `renderCard` method. `selectedLanguageQuestions` is an array of objects.

```
<Swipe 
   data={selectedLanguageQuestions}
   activeQuestion={activeQuestion}
   renderCard={(item, i) => this.renderCard(item, i)}
   onSwipeLeft={(ques, i) => this.setState({ activeQuestion: i })}
   onSwipeRight={(ques, i) => this.setState({ activeQuestion: i })}
/>
```

Render method of Swipe:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderCards()}
      </View>
    );
}

renderCards() {
    return this.props.data.map((item, i) => {
      if (i === this.state.index) {
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={i}
            style={[this.getCardStyle(), styles.cardStyle]}
            {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
          >
            {this.props.renderCard(item, i)}
          </Animated.View>
        );
      }

      return (
        <Animated.View 
          key={i} 
          style={[styles.cardStyle, { opacity: 0 }]}
          {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
          {this.props.renderCard(item, i)}
        </Animated.View>
      )
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure about react native, I have a similar react example, https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-voice-i9jpe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Asutosh Yea my options index is coming fine. I am talking about the first map which is the questionIndex.

Comment: Please show the code where you are calling renderCard

Comment: @Asutosh Added a working demo with the issue in the question. Check the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@sl-a-sh/swipe-test)

Comment: Is the `index` that goes in here `<Text style={styles.question}>{index + 1}. {item.question}</Text>` a correct one?

Comment: @x00 Yes that is coming correct. The only time I am getting wrong index is on the onPress method of the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like on Swipe.js line 137

```
return (
     <Animated.View 
       key={i} 
       style={[styles.cardStyle, { opacity: 0 }]}
       {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
     >
       {this.props.renderCard(item, i)}
     </Animated.View>
)
```

You are keeping the answers above each others, so what's happening exactly is that you are clicking on the answers that have 0 opacity, but because you don't see them, you think the visible answers are those getting the event. So what I suggest is that you disable the events on the answers that have 0 opacity, like so:

```
return (
    <Animated.View 
       key={i} 
       pointerEvents="none"
       style={[styles.cardStyle, { opacity: 0 }]}
       {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
    >
       {this.props.renderCard(item, i)}
    </Animated.View>
)
```

Just added `pointerEvents="none"` attribute; to see how the questions were interrupting your "press", set the opacity to something above 0.5 and you will see the problem.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Wow. I never would have guessed that. That is indeed working. Thanks